# Postgresql update query syntax error in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql

I have to create a update procedure, so i created a function and given only below query

```
 CREATE FUNCTION public.testf()
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$begin
update tt pp
set status  = 'Ok'
return true;
end;$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.testf()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

returns error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPDATE" LINE 5: AS $BODY$UPDATE

return type I have given is int4range

What I am doing wrong

Please help
THanks

Comment: Please post the entire definition of the procedure

Comment: i have only this line

Comment: That's not a procedure/function, that's a single SQL query. Post the complete code.

Comment: Also, is your table really named `table`? That might cause issues, as it is a keyword. Use `UPDATE "table" …`

Comment: code updated now

Answer (score 2):

Pulling out my crystal ball, I see:

- You created the function with `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.
- You didn't surround the function body with `BEGIN ... END;`.

If your function is just a single SQL statement, use `LANGUAGE sql`.

Else, use the block-centered PL/pgSQL syntax properly.

Comment: Ok, my crystal ball cannot penetrate that deep. You'll have to edit the question and show the complete function and the error message.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, and the next error message will be that neither implementation will return a `int4range`.

Comment: Yes. Where should that `int4range`come from?

Comment: I have updated post whatever its showing in sql tab

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `;` to end the UPDATE statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.testf()
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
begin
  update tt pp
    set status  = 'Ok';  --<< here

  return true;
end;
$BODY$;
```